# docker exposing multiple ports - not working

Tags: docker, port, dockerfile

I have a docker image that on running executes the following script

```
java -jar myjar.jar & disown
python2.7 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9999
```

the `myjar.jar` program exposes a webservice and listens to port 11111.
In my Docker file i expose these 2 ports like so:

```
EXPOSE 9999 11111
```

This is how i run the image:

```
docker run --rm -p 9999:9999 -p 11111:11111 myimage
```

I can access the python web process with the url `localhost:9999/admin/`.
When i try to access the java web service with `curl localhost:11111/myservice?wsdl` I get connection refused.
When i enter the container with a terminal using

```
docker exec -i -t <container_id> bash
```

and run `curl localhost:11111/myservice?wsdl` i get the wsdl content.
Where is my port binding going wrong? (or port exposing? or maybe the way i am running the jar file?)

Comment: it may be firewall problem !!

Comment: is your java program binding on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` ; or is it binding on `0.0.0.0` as it should?